# Webpack how to compile all my scss file without generating the useless same-name js file

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I use webpack ^5.65.0.

I want to compile all my scss file into css but I have to use multiple `import` in my entry `index.js` like

```
import './index.scss';
import './test.scss'
...
```

I do not want to use import in the `index.js` file and think it can be done by webpack settings(I am not sure).

My `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {

    devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map',
    mode: isDev ? 'development' : 'production',
    entry: {
        index: './src/index.js',
        login: './src/login.js',
        test:'./test.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash:6].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                use: ['cache-loader','babel-loader'],
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')]
                
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sc|sa|c)ss/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')]
        
            }
         ]
     }
  }
```

I have no idea, then add a `test.js` to put all the scss `import` in it and add it to the entry.But the output will also has a `test.xxxxxx.js` file in the `dist` folder and I do not want it though.

So,what is the right way to meet my requirement.

Is it possible to just compile all `scss` file without `import` in the entry `js` file and do not generate the same-name js file in output folder?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to automatically build all `*.scss` files that are in `./src` is that right?

Thankfully webpack.config.js is a js file so you can generate the config programmatically.

Expanding @biodiscus answer to automatically fetch the files:

```js
// => webpack.config.js

const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const scssFiles = fs.readdirSync("./src").filter(function (file) {
  return file.match(/.*\.scss$/);
});
const scssEntries = scssFiles.map((filename) => {
  const filenameWithoutExtension = filename.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
  const entryName = `style_` + filenameWithoutExtension;
  return { [entryName]: "./src/" + filename };
});

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: "./src/index.js",
    login: './src/login.js',
    test:'./test.js'
    ...Object.assign({}, ...scssEntries),
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      { // a loader loads file with matching extension no matter
        // if it is listed in entry: or imported inside js
        test: /\.(sc|sa|c)ss/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src")],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

So the changes are:
First, get names of all scss files:

```js
const scssFiles = fs.readdirSync("./src").filter(function (file) {
  return file.match(/.*\.scss$/);
});
const scssEntries = scssFiles.map((filename) => {
  const filenameWithoutExtension = filename.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
  const entryName = `style_` + filenameWithoutExtension;
  return { [entryName]: "./src/" + filename };
});
```

Second, append them to the list of entries:

```js
entry: {
  index: "./src/index.js",
  login: './src/login.js',
  test:'./test.js'
  ...Object.assign({}, ...scssEntries),
},
```

and third, **this is important:**

```js
output: {
  filename: "[name].js", // <-- use template for named output
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
},
```

Also, notice how I prepended the entry names with `style_`. Otherwise `index.js` and `index.scss` would have both same entry name resulting in only one being built.

Comment: Sorry,maybe I do not explain clearly.I post a new thread and hope your kindly help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70911414/webpack-remove-more-js-files-in-output-folder