# webpack remove extra js files in output folder

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I would like to compile all `scss` file but without generating the extra `js` file,currently my code structure is:

```
-public
 -index.html
 -login.html
-src
 -index.js
 -index.scss
 -login.js
 -login.scss
 -test.scss
```

I want to generate in my dist folder like

```
-dist
 -css
   -login.xxxxxx.css
   -index.xxxxxx.css
   -test.xxxxxx.css
 -index.xxxxxx.js
 -index.html
 -login.xxxxxx.js
 -login.html
```

In my last thread, I get to know  [webpack-remove-empty-scripts](https://github.com/webdiscus/webpack-remove-empty-scripts) and my `webpack.config.js` like below.

```
npm install webpack-remove-empty-scripts --save-dev
```

```
'use strict';
const path = require('path');

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin = require('webpack-remove-empty-scripts');

const fs = require("fs");
const scssFiles = fs.readdirSync("./src").filter(function (file) {
    return file.match(/.*\.scss$/);
  });
  const scssEntries = scssFiles.map((filename) => {
    const filenameWithoutExtension = filename.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
    const entryName = filenameWithoutExtension;
    return { [entryName]: "./src/" + filename };
  });

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
const config = require('./public/config')[isDev ? 'dev' : 'build'];

module.exports = {

    devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map',
    mode: isDev ? 'development' : 'production',
    entry: {
        index: './src/index.js',
        login: './src/login.js',
       ...Object.assign({}, ...scssEntries)
      },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash:6].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                use: ['cache-loader','babel-loader'],
               
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sc|sa|c)ss/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')]
                // exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            
            {
                test: /.html$/,
                use: 'html-withimg-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
       new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html', 
            config: config.template,
            minify: {
                removeAttributeQuotes: false, 
                collapseWhitespace: false, 
            },
            chunks: ['index']
           
        }),
        new RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin(),      
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:6].css'       
        }),    
    ]
}
```

If I do not use this plugin, it will generate three js file in dist. If I use it, my `index.xxxxxx.js` and `login.xxxxxx.js` are also be removed and there is no js file at all.

What is the problem?I want to keep js file generated by `.js` of entry but remove js file generated by `.scss` of entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with the usage of the webpack entry:

```js
entry: {
  index: './src/index.js',
  login: './src/login.js',
  ...Object.assign({}, ...scssEntries) // <== HERE IS THE PROBLEM
},
```

This line `...Object.assign({}, ...scssEntries)` generate following:

```js
{ 
  index: './src/index.scss', 
  login: './src/login.scss' 
}
```

Then two object will be merged via `...`.
But, this both objects have same keys: `index` and `login`, therefore last object, contained same keys but with `.scss` files, override first object with `.js` files.

The merging of:

```js
entry: {
  index: './src/index.js',
  login: './src/login.js',
  ... { index: './src/index.scss', login: './src/login.scss' }
},
```

has the result:

```js
entry: {
  index: './src/index.scss', 
  login: './src/login.scss' 
},
```

#### Solution

Use advanced syntax of webpack entry-point to define files with same `basename` (filename without extention).

Change the webpack entry:

```js
entry: {
  index: './src/index.js', // => dist/index.xxxxxx.js
  login: './src/login.js', // => dist/login.xxxxxx.js
  // use uniq key in entry
  indexCss: {
    import: './src/index.scss',
    filename: 'css/index.[contenthash:6].css' // => dist/css/index.xxxxxx.css
  },
  // use uniq key in entry
  loginCss: {
    import: './src/login.scss',
    filename: 'css/login.[contenthash:6].css' // => dist/css/login.xxxxxx.css
  }
},
```

Or other variant:

```js
entry: {
  index: './src/index.js', // => dist/index.xxxxxx.js
  login: './src/login.js', // => dist/login.xxxxxx.js
  // use uniq key in entry
  'css/index': './src/index.scss',
  // use uniq key in entry
  'css/login': './src/login.scss'
},
```

In this case use

```
plugin: [
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: '[name].[contenthash:6].css', // <= remove `css/` from filename
  }),
  //...
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It could make it,but I need the index.html to import index.css and login.html to import login.css after building automatically.In this way, it does not work?

Comment: I used to add css importing in the entry index.js .Now i could not import it manually and is there any other solution based on your answer to complie index.html with corresponding index.scss,test.scc annd login.html with login.css?

Comment: What do you mean "building automatically"?  Injection of SCSS files via `...Object.assign({}, ...scssEntries)`? If you has same `basename` for html, css, js, then no, it does not work. The webpack entry can contain only unique keys.

Comment: Sorry for late response.In other words, the generated html does not has the <link> for the generated css file.I do not want to use `import` in js file (as this is what I do at the very beginning), is that reasonable?

Comment: When using import scss in js, the HtmlWebpackPlugin automatically inserts  the <link> into HTML head. This is a popular but dirty way, bad practice.

I prefer to define all styles in a webpack entry manually, without globally scanning ./src, and writing HTML with already included <link href="/web/path/to/styles.css">.
How mutch has you style files in a project, 5-10-100? If are only 5-10 you can define for each style an uniq key in webpack entry manually, see the solution above.